# Loop with Paging and Limit C#

Tags: c#, loops

How to stop a loop after 12 Items?

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mapper = new Mapper();
        foreach (List<int> page in mapper.LoadListPaged(5, 12))
            Console.WriteLine($"Start: {page.Min()} --- End: {page.Max()}");

        Console.ReadLine();
     }
}

public class Mapper
{
    private int _index = 0;

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> LoadListPaged(int pageSize, int limit)
    {
        int pageCount = 0;
        var result = new List<int>();

        while (_index < limit)
        {
            pageCount = 0;
            result = new List<int>();

            while (pageCount < pageSize)
            {
                pageCount++;
                result.Add(_index++);
            }
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The result should look like this:

> Start: 0 --- End: 4
>   Start: 5 --- End: 9
>   Start: 10 --- End: 12

(Note it ends at 14, not 2)

Thank you!

Comment: How is it related to sql? If it's part of sql query, paging in memory is not the correct way.

Comment: i want to page through huge sql data table, with SELECT TOP PageSize and optional stop if limit ist bigger than x.

Comment: Then check you sql engine's paging capability. BTW, you code can be shorten (less interesting) to `return Enumerable.Range(0, limit).GroupBy(e => e / pageSize).Select(g => g);`

Answer (score 1):

```
while (pageCount < pageSize && _index < limit)
```

Comment: @PaulF yes and no. <= will give "End: 12" as Serzhunuto asked. However, it will result in 13 elements in output sequence, while I think meaning of method is to return 12 items, not 13.

Comment: thanks all and sorry, i want to stop after 12 Items so the End: 11 ist correct.

Comment: In that case the answer is correct & have upvoted accordingly